# SQL Server 2014 installation fails: An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail

Tags: sql-server, installation

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2014 Enterprise x64 on a 64-bit machine running Windows 7 SP1. I'm trying to install side-by-side with a SQL Server 2008 R2 installation.

I work through the Setup Wizard with everything looking fine except for a warning about the firewall (which I think I can't resolve until after installation). At the appropriate step, I give the new installation a different name (MSSQLSERVER2014) than the existing MSSQLSERVER.

When I finally start it running, it fails. To be specific, everything fails except for the Data Quality Client and the Documentation.

Here's the log that's created (with personal details removed):

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068643839
  Start time:                    2014-12-15 11:50:31
  End time:                      2014-12-15 11:54:42
  Requested action:              Install

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for Adv_SSMS:        Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for Conn:            Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for BC:              Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for SSMS:            Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for RS:              Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for DQ:              Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for FullText:        Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for AS:              Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for SNAC_SDK:        Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  XXXXXXXX
  Machine processor count:       8
  OS version:                    Windows 7
  OS service pack:               Service Pack 1
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured
  SQL Server 2008 R2   MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER         Database Engine Services                 1033                 Enterprise Edition   10.51.2550.0    No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2008 R2   MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER         SQL Server Replication                   1033                 Enterprise Edition   10.51.2550.0    No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2008 R2   MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER         Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search 1033                 Enterprise Edition   10.51.2500.0    No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2008 R2   MSSQLSERVER          MSAS10_50.MSSQLSERVER          Analysis Services                        1033                 Enterprise Edition   10.51.2500.0    No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2008 R2   MSSQLSERVER          MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER          Reporting Services - Native              1033                 Enterprise Edition   10.51.2550.0    No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2008 R2                                                       Management Tools - Basic                 1033                 Enterprise Edition   10.51.2550.0    No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2008 R2                                                       Management Tools - Complete              1033                 Enterprise Edition   10.51.2500.0    No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2008 R2                                                       Client Tools Connectivity                1033                 Enterprise Edition   10.51.2500.0    No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2008 R2                                                       Client Tools Backwards Compatibility     1033                 Enterprise Edition   10.51.2500.0    No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2008 R2                                                       Client Tools SDK                         1033                 Enterprise Edition   10.51.2500.0    No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2008 R2                                                       Integration Services                     1033                 Enterprise Edition   10.51.2550.0    No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2014                                                          Data Quality Client                      1033                 Enterprise Edition   12.0.2000.8     No         Yes       

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2014 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2014
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       12
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         F:\English\SQLServer2014\EnterpriseEdition\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Enterprise

Product Update Status:
  None discovered.

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\SQLAgent$MSSQLSERVER2014
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS12.MSSQLSERVER2014\OLAP\Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS12.MSSQLSERVER2014\OLAP\Config
  ASDATADIR:                     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS12.MSSQLSERVER2014\OLAP\Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS12.MSSQLSERVER2014\OLAP\Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSOLAP$MSSQLSERVER2014
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            XXXXXXXX\xxxxxx
  ASTEMPDIR:                     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS12.MSSQLSERVER2014\OLAP\Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Automatic
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141215_115030\ConfigurationFile.ini
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    false
  ENU:                           true
  ERRORREPORTING:                false
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE, FULLTEXT, DQ, AS, RS, CONN, BC, SSMS, ADV_SSMS
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher$MSSQLSERVER2014
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             D:\SQLData
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER2014
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER2014
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          <empty>
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              DefaultSharePointMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  NT Service\ReportServer$MSSQLSERVER2014
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         <empty>
  SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQL$MSSQLSERVER2014
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           XXXXXXXX\xxxxxx
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQMREPORTING:                  false
  TCPENABLED:                    1
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141215_115030\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Management Tools - Complete
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       Client Tools Connectivity
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       Client Tools Backwards Compatibility
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       Management Tools - Basic
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       Reporting Services - Native
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       Data Quality Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       Analysis Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20141215_115030\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Comment: Someone elsewhere asked whether I'd tried running the Setup as admin. I have now, and it changes nothing.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Solved my own problem with some more searching. The short version of the solution is that I needed to uninstall the SQL Server 2012 Native Client before doing this installation. (Not sure how that got installed on my machine; best guess is some Windows update.)

The resources that led me to the solution were:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/889167a7-1e51-4911-87fd-f1ed183fb839/failed-installation-of-sql-server-2014?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade - which led me to the details.txt file telling me exactly what failed.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/769695/install-fail-sql-server-2012-developer-edition-an-error-occurred-for-a-dependency-of-the-feature

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24563/not-able-to-install-any-piece-of-sql-server-2012-dev-edition-on-my-windows-7/25832#25832

Comment: This is still relevant. Native Client installed by IIS as part of WebDeploy installation prohibits the MS SQL to be installed on the same machine.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov Spot On! That was my issue. WebDeploy installing Native Client 2012. Once I uninstalled it, 2014 Tools installation completed like a charm.

Comment: It is Nov 2022 and this is still relevant. As always Microsoft experience is pathetic. Trying to install for last two hours. Thanks for tip.

Answer (score 9):

Well, this is going to sound a little crazy, but if you are installing from a mounted ISO, extracting the ISO out to disk, as recommended on this [Error Installing SQL Server 2012 Management Tools MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1a90b732-8bee-4891-a49c-eada5d18b00e/error-installing-sql-server-2012-management-tools?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade), cleared up the error for me. I used 7-Zip to extract it (the thread suggests that it won't work if you use WinZIP to extract it).

Comment: Perfect! This was the fix for me.

Comment: This worked for me too, thanks. SQL Server 2017 to 2019.

Comment: the best answer

Comment: It's not crazy. We think mounted iso is like having an installation disk, but it is different. This iso file is not meant to be burned in the disk.